# invoke cloud function only for certain user agents in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to invoke a firebase function only if the request is coming from the Google bot user agent.

currently I´m invoking the function on every http request.

1. Request comes in
2. Check the user agent
3. User Agent is **Google** then `response.send("hello google")`
4. User Agent is not **Google** render the index.html from firebase hosting.

---

```
request({uri: "http://example.com/index.html"}, 
    function(error, response, body) {
        res.send(body)
    });
});
```

this will cause a loop because the function will request the index.html file from firebase hosting and doing that will invoke the function again. so I think is better to call the function only if the request comes from google user agent

is this possible? any ideas to solve this problem? thank you!

Comment: Redirecting to example.com/index.html wont work?

Comment: It will trigger the function again

Answer (score 0):

Google bot issues requests with specifics user agents, virtually all of them containing the keyword Googlebot. Just get the header and check if it includes the keyword.
Supposing you are using express:

```
if (req.get('User-Agent').toLowerCase().includes('googlebot')) {
    res.send("hello google")
} else {
    request({uri: "http://example.com/index.html"}, 
        function(error, response, body) {
            res.send(body)
        });
    });
    //or res.redirect(302, "http://example.com/index.html")
}
```

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/googlebot/
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943

Comment: That’s what I’m doing now but I want to invoke the function only if the user agent contains google. Also doing what you suggest will cause a loop